# Creating loops from xml data

Tags: python, xml, loops

Please look at the following code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse("C:\Users\...\xml") #This is just the address to the document
soccerfeed = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("SoccerFeed")[0] 
soccerdocument = soccerfeed.getElementsByTagName("SoccerDocument")[0] 
competition = soccerdocument.getElementsByTagName("Competition")[0] 
country = competition.getElementsByTagName("Country")[0].firstChild.data 
name = competition.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].firstChild.data  
season = competition.getElementsByTagName("Stat")[1].firstChild.data 
matchday = competition.getElementsByTagName('Stat')[3].firstChild.data   
lst = [country, name, season, "matchday: "+ matchday]    
print lst

#Match Data
MatchData = soccerdocument.getElementsByTagName("MatchData")[0]    
for MatchInfo in MatchData:
    MatchInfo = MatchData.getElementsByTagName("MatchInfo")[0]  
    Attendance = MatchInfo.getElementsByTagName("Attendance")[0].firstChild.data    
    Result = MatchInfo.getElementsByTagName("Result")[0]   
    print (MatchInfo, "Attendance: "+ Attendance)
```

So I just wrote this code to parse some data from a xml file. I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Javi\Desktop\csvfile.py", line 28, in <module>
    for MatchInfo in MatchData:
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: what does print MatchData output?

Comment: Have you considered ElementTree or even better: lxml ?
This would be faster and easier than with minidom.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over return value of `getElementsByTagName`.

Replace following line

```
MatchData = soccerdocument.getElementsByTagName("MatchData")[0]
```

to

```
MatchData = soccerdocument.getElementsByTagName("MatchData")
```